# Insert Update Triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using Triggers:

We have 2 tables like named table1 and table2

if we insert anything into table1 instead of that it should get inserted into table2 and must compare with table1 whether already that row or data existing..
if existed then it should get updated into table1 else it should get inserted as new row into table1..

Comment: Why do you need to insert into table2 at all, why not directly compare with table1? Or even better why not do the insert with a merge statment and avoid triggers altogehter.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use following trigger to identify insert or update or deleted state of your table

```
CREATE TRIGGER Audit 
    ON dbo.Employee 
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS 
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) > 0 
    BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) > 0 
        BEGIN 
            -- update! 
            INSERT AuditEmployee 
            (EmployeeID, UserName, Operation) 
            SELECT EmployeeID, SUSER_SNAME(), 'U' 
            FROM inserted 
        END 
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            -- insert! 
            INSERT AuditEmployee 
            (EmployeeID, UserName, Operation) 
            SELECT EmployeeID, SUSER_SNAME(), 'I' 
            FROM inserted 
        END 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        -- delete! 
        INSERT AuditEmployee 
        (EmployeeID, UserName, Operation) 
        SELECT EmployeeID, SUSER_SNAME(), 'D' 
        FROM deleted 
    END 
GO
```